# Boosting fields at query time in Standard Request Handler from Solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am developing a search engine app using Asp.Net, C# and Solrnet. I use the standard request handler. Is there a way I can boost the fields at query time from inside the solrconfig.xml file itself. Just like the "qf" field for Dismax handler.
Right now am searching like "field1:value^1.5 field2:value^1.2 field3:value^0.8" and this is done in the middle tier. I want Solr itself to do this using standard request handler.
Can I write a similar kind of thing inside standard req handler?

Here is my solrconfig file.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <str name="hl">true</str>
     <str name="hl.snippets">3</str>
     <str name="hl.fragsize">25</str>
     <str name="qf">file_description^100.0 file_content^6.0 file_name^10.0 file_comments^4.0
     </str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>             
   </arr>
 </requestHandler>
```

Regards

Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

Inside a 'requestHandler' element in solrconfig.xml you can add

```
<requestHandler>
   <str name="qf">
       field1^3.0 field2^2.0 field3^1.0
   </str>
</requestHandler>
```

to provide a predefined field bias, I hope I have understood your question right? :-)

Comment: Hi. But am not able to see the results if I add this in my solrconfig.xml file. I have edited the post to add my req handler code in solrconfig. But, if have my query string as "file_description:result^1.0 file_content:result^0.6 file_name:result^0.5 file_comments:result^0.8", am able to see the required result.